# How to schedule application termination in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks

I have an `app.exe` file which I want to be terminated every monday at 19:00.

Is it possible to schedule tha task which terminates `app.exe` ?

Comment: CMD -> `taskkill /?` = "This tool is used to terminate tasks by process id (PID) or image name."

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ok, but do you suggest that the solution is run another .exe at 19:00 which runs process `taskkill /?` ? Or taskill/? can be run by Windows Scheduler itself?

Answer (score 2):

## creation

```
schtasks /create /tn termination /tr "taskkill /f /t /im app.exe" /sc weekly /d mon /st 19:00
```

creating a task named *termination* (`/tn`) that runs weekly (`/sc weekly`) every monday (`/d mon`) at **s**tart **t**ime of 19:00 (`/st`)

## viewing

```
schtasks /query /tn termination
```

viewing the created task queried by name

```
Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
termination                              2014.11.3 7:00:00 PM   Ready
```

ps:

here `tasklist` terminates the process **t**ree (`/t`) by it's **im**age name (`/im`)  **f**orcefully (`/f`) (without prompting for confirmation)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding what @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 has suggested:
Create a scheduled task in task scheduler and task to run should be:

```
taskkill /im <your application name>.exe /f
```

You may have to schedule this task to run as administrator.